# Converter objeto data.frame em numeric

Tags: data.frame

Tenho um arquivo data.frame e preciso converter em valores numéricos para fazer soma de colunas.  Utilizei o código "dicpes<-as.numeric(dicpes)" para tentar converter e apareceu a seguinte mensagem: "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.

Observando resposta de outro tópico, resolvi separar as colunas do objeto e convertê-los individualmente em valores numéricos usando o seguinte código:

```
inicio<- dicpes[,1]
inicio<-as.numeric(as.character(inicio)) # transformando em números
tamanho<- dicpes[,2]
tamanho<-as.numeric(as.character(tamanho)) # transformando em números
variavel<- dicpes[,3] # coluna em formato texto
variavel<- as.character(variavel) # manter em formato texto
dicpes<- cbind(inicio, tamanho, variavel)
```

Entretanto, quando o último comando, as duas primeiras colunas (inicio e tamanho) voltam a ser lidas com texto também e não consigo efetuar a soma. Como contornar esse problema?

Answer (score 1):

@Julio Cesar, você não pode fazer aquele tipo de operação com um data.frame. Algumas soluções para o seu problema:

```
df <- data.frame("col_1" = as.character(seq(1,10)), "col_2" = as.character(seq(11,20)))
```

---

**1. Separar as trasformações individualmente por colunas**

```
df$col_1 <- as.numeric(df$col_1)
df$col_2 <- as.numeric(df$col_2)
```

---

**2. Usar lapply**

```
df[, c(1,2)] <- lapply(df[c(1,2)], as.numeric)
```

Com lapply, eu posso selecionar somente as colunas que eu quero que sejam transformadas.

---

**3. Solução tidyverse**

```
df <- df %>% mutate_at(c(1, 2), as.numeric)
```

---